# Output tensors to a Model must be Keras tensors

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

I was trying to make a model learned from difference between two model output. So I made code like below. But it occurred error read:

> TypeError: Output tensors to a Model must be Keras tensors. Found:
>   Tensor("sub:0", shape=(?, 10), dtype=float32)

I have found related answer including `lambda`, but I couldn't solve this issue.
Does anyone know this issue?
It might be seen converting tensor to keras's tensor.

Thx in advance.

```
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.models import Model
from keras.models import Sequential

left_branch = Sequential()
left_branch.add(Dense(10, input_dim=784))

right_branch = Sequential()
right_branch.add(Dense(10, input_dim=784))

diff = left_branch.output - right_branch.output

model = Model(inputs=[left_branch.input, right_branch.input], outputs=[diff])
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='binary_crossentropy', loss_weights=[1.])

model.summary(line_length=150)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's better to keep all operations done by a layer, do not subtract outputs like that (I wouldn't risk hidden errors for doing things differently from what the documentation expects):

```
from keras.layers import *

def negativeActivation(x):
    return -x

left_branch = Sequential()
left_branch.add(Dense(10, input_dim=784))

right_branch = Sequential()
right_branch.add(Dense(10, input_dim=784))

negativeRight = Activation(negativeActivation)(right_branch.output) 
diff = Add()([left_branch.output,negativeRight])

model = Model(inputs=[left_branch.input, right_branch.input], outputs=diff)
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='binary_crossentropy', loss_weights=[1.])
```

When joining models like that, I do prefer using the `Model` way of doing it, with layers, instead of using `Sequential`:

```
def negativeActivation(x):
    return -x

leftInput = Input((784,))
rightInput = Input((784,))

left_branch = Dense(10)(leftInput) #Dense(10) creates a layer
right_branch = Dense(10)(rightInput) #passing the input creates the output

negativeRight = Activation(negativeActivation)(right_branch) 
diff = Add()([left_branch,negativeRight])

model = Model(inputs=[leftInput, rightInput], outputs=diff)
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='binary_crossentropy', loss_weights=[1.])
```

With this, you can create other models with the same layers, they will share the same weights:

```
leftModel = Model(leftInput,left_branch)
rightModel = Model(rightInput,right_branch)
fullModel = Model([leftInput,rightInput],diff)
```

Training one of them will affect the others if they share the same layer. 
You can train just the right part in the full model by making `left_branch.trainable = False` before compiling (or compile again for training), for instance.

Comment: :) -- Also, not necessary for this answer, but instead of using `Activation` as I did, it could also be a good idea to understand `Lambda` layers.

Answer (score 0):

I think I solve this, but it might be exact solution.
I added some code like below :

```
diff = left_branch.output - right_branch.output
setattr(diff, '_keras_history', getattr(right_branch.output, '_keras_history'))
setattr(diff, '_keras_shape', getattr(right_branch.output, '_keras_shape'))
setattr(diff, '_uses_learning_phase', getattr(right_branch.output, '_uses_learning_phase'))
```

The reason why the error occur is diff tensor doesn't have attr named _keras_history so on. So adding intentionally them to diff tensor could prevent above error. I checked original code ran and being possible to learn.